# Is the scalar product between the average of $\{a_1,...,a_m\}$ and some $a_i$ non negative?

Tags: matrices, optimization, linear-programming

If $a_1,...,a_m$ are rows of a matrix $A\in \Bbb R^{m\times n}$ do we have that $\langle a_i,a_1+...+a_m\rangle\geq0$ ?

For context I'm trying to prove that in a full rank bounded polyhedron $P\subset\Bbb R^n$, $P=\{x:Ax\leq b\}$ There exist vertices $v_1,...,v_{n+1}$ affinely independent.

The part I need this specific result for is showing that if $m>n$ (obviousely $m\geq n$ because of the full rank but the boundedness will imply $m>n$)

My reasoning:

If $m=n$ then by calling $x_0$ a basic feasible solution of $P$, the set $\{x_0-\lambda(a_1+...+a_n)\ :\ \lambda>0\}$ is an unbounded subset of $P$

In fact let $\lambda$ be positive. $A(x_0-\lambda(a_1+...a_n))\leq b-\lambda A(a_1+...+a_n)$ which I want to be smaller a equal to the vector $b$.

Comment: To me the statement about a full rank polyhedron is geometrically obvious and could be asserted without further proof. It's essentially the definition of "full rank".

Comment: which statement?

Comment: The one in the second paragraph that you say motivated your question.

Comment: Oh if it is obvious than how would you prove it? The one about affinely independent points?

Comment: What's the geometric definition of full rank? Presumably it's "contained in no affine space of lower dimension". Then the assertion is just a restatement of the definition. If this doesn't help you there's nothing more I can say. Go with the upvoted answer.

Comment: Yeah but you didn’t use the boundedness. This is not necessarily true without the boundedness

Answer (score 2):

We have $$\langle a_1 + \dots  +a_m, a_1 + \dots + a_m\rangle = \|a_1 + \dots + a_m\|^2 \ge 0$$ so by linearity $$\langle a_1, a_1 + \dots + a_m\rangle + \dots + \langle a_m, a_1 + \dots + a_m\rangle \ge 0$$ and therefore at least one of the terms $\langle a_i, a_1 + \dots + a_m\rangle$ must be nonnegative.